# Preload images on this script

Tags: javascript, optimization, preload

I'm using this script to load images on two of my sites (script is hosted on other site). Script loads on the website and place the image inside a `div` with the `ID` `div-to-load-external-image`

The problem is that **PageSpeed Insights** is telling me to `preload` these images and I don't have a clue how to do it...

Any help?

```
var imagesvar = [
["/goout/mylink/", "https://picsum.photos/300/145", "Title 1", "tracking-image"],
["/goout/mylink/", "https://picsum.photos/300/145", "Title 2", "tracking-image"],
["/goout/mylink/", "https://picsum.photos/300/145", "Title 3", "tracking-image"],
["/goout/mylink/", "https://picsum.photos/300/145", "Title 4", "tracking-image"],
];
function shuffle(b) {
    var j, x, i;
    for (i = b.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        x = b[i];
        b[i] = b[j];
        b[j] = x;
    }
    return b;
}
shuffle(imagesvar);
document.getElementById('div-to-load-external-image').innerHTML = '<a href="'+imagesvar[0][0]+'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><span class="myclass">New</span><div class="myimage" style="text-align:center;"><img src="'+imagesvar[0][1]+'" width="300px" height="145px" alt="'+imagesvar[0][3]+'" onClick="gtag(\'event\', \'TodNav\', {\'event_category\': \'tod\',\'event_label\': \'tod-'+imagesvar[0][3]+'\'});" /></div><h2 class="title">'+imagesvar[0][2]+'</h2></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can preload images in the `<head>` section of your HTML document using the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="preload" as="image" href="someImage">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="someImage">
  </body>
</html>
```

Found an interesting article you might want to read: https://web.dev/preload-responsive-images/

Comment: I want to `preload` them on the script because I don't  have access to the `head` of the page

Comment: You can access the `<head>` tag with `document.head`. I think you can go for something like:`const link = document.createElement("link")`
`link.rel = "preload"` `link.as = "image"` `link.href = ...` and finally`document.head.appendChild(link)`